# parentsUntil not stopping at parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using parentsUntil() to open all uls above the current link.  I've read the documentation, however for some reason it's not working as expected.  The following hides everything right up to the top of the dom.

html

```
<ul class ='product-categories'>
    <li><a href ='http://example.com/link1'>Link 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href ='http://example.com/link/sub-link1'>Sub link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href ='http://example.com/link/sub-link2'>Sub link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href ='http://example.com/link/sub-link3'>Sub link 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href ='http://example.com/link2'>Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href ='http://example.com/link3'>Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href ='http://example.com/link4'>Link 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

jquery

```
var url = window.location.href;
$('a[href= "' + url + '"]')
    .parentsUntil( $('ul.product-categories') )
    .slideToggle('fast');
```

It skips product-categories amd just keeps on going.  If I provide 'ul' as a filter:

```
$('a[href= "' + url + '"]')
    .parentsUntil( $('ul.product-categories'), 'ul' )
    .slideToggle('fast');
```

It toggles every ul on the page except for product-categories.

Edit:  Am assuming this is due to a conflict on the acutal page, as the fiddle is working fine.  Have taken down links and will try to find another way to do this.

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Your HTML is `product-categories`, your jQuery is `product_categories`.  The two must match.

Comment: Typo is not in the actual page.

Comment: Your production page shows as empty, pretty hard to find out what the problem is from there.

Comment: Really?  I use Ip blocking, but I've taken it all down.  You can try [this](http://imw1248.info/product-category/bamboo-cutting-board/round-cutting-board/)

Comment: Btw, your fiddle had the same dash vs underscore issue.

Comment: Oops!  Blaming lack of sleep :)

Comment: [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FEt9m/2/) seems to work fine though.

Comment: Yes, fiddle works, but code doesn't work on my page.  Blaming a conflict.  Think I'll just find another way to do this.

Answer (score -1):

It should be

```
$('a[href= "' + url + '"]').parentsUntil('ul.product-categories').slideToggle('fast');
```

You pass the function a selector, not a jQuery object. (*edit* — well you *can* pass a jQuery object, but in this case it'd be silly.)

Comment: Should have mentioned, tried that, still hides toggles everything on the page.

Comment: @Talknerdytome [works for me!](http://jsfiddle.net/vWwS9/1/) Note that your HTML has a dash and your JavaScript has an underscore between "product" and "categories".

Comment: @Pointy Indeed, if the wanted it to work the way he first programmed it, he'd have to implement `.eq(0)` alike in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/54cb4/). Which of course, wouldn't actually be using the `parentsUntil()` for it's original intention at all.

Comment: Working on a fiddle, the dash was a typo, not in my actual code

Comment: Actually, the [jQuery doc](https://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/) says that it's OK to pass a jQuery object to `.parentsUntil()` so I don't think that is the issue.  The dash vs. underscore is probably at least part of the issue.

Comment: @jfriend00 well yes I guess so but it's kind-of pointless.  Also I'm not sure what'd happen if there were multiple `<ul>` elements like that.